# Compiling csv into one master file then output error?

Tags: csv, compilation, output

I am trying to do something for my company. Basically what I need to do is

1. Compile all the csv in a folder into one master file.
2. From the master file, output potential error code found in the master file to the user.

The key thing of this is to make it automated. Meaning, I only want to press one button or do one step and it will do step 1 and 2 for me immediately.

The question is I have no idea what software or coding I should be using or looking at. Will be great if someone can enlighten on how I should approach this?

Note: I have limited knowledge of such things but am willing to learn.

====

Edit:

To give better example,

```
  File1.csv
  Voltage    Ampere     Power    Error    ID
==============================================
  6V         3A        6W     18-ABB    000123
  8V         2A        7W       0       123991
  8V         10A       25W    25-ASB    461233
  10V        23A       10W    18-ABB    248811
  1V         2A        9W       0       321881

  File2.csv
  Voltage    Ampere     Power    Error    ID
==============================================
  6V         4A        6W       0       312313
  3V         5A        7W       0       123312
  2V         10A       5W     25-ASB    461643
  1V         2A        10W    18-ABB    656474
  11V        2A        9W       0       124242
```

What I want to achieve,

Compile file1 and file 2 into one master.csv as below,

```
  master.csv
  File1
  Voltage    Ampere     Power    Error    ID
==============================================
  6V         3A        6W     18-ABB    000123
  8V         2A        7W       0       123991
  8V         10A       25W    25-ASB    461233
  10V        23A       10W    18-ABB    248811
  1V         2A        9W       0       321881
  File2
  Voltage    Ampere     Power    Error    ID
==============================================
  6V         4A        6W       0       312313
  3V         5A        7W       0       123312
  2V         10A       5W     25-ASB    461643
  1V         2A        10W    18-ABB    656474
  11V        2A        9W       0       124242
```

The master.csv must contain the filenamewhen it is being compile. From master.csv, find and isolate the machine ID with the error code 18-ABB or 25-ASB (it will be variable but if its 0,it means no error) into a new called for example outputerror.csv file.

The headers (Voltage etc.) needs to be carry forward to the new outputerror.csv file.

Hence, the outputerror.csv should look like this,

```
      outputerror.csv
      Voltage    Ampere     Power    Error   ID
    ==============================================
   File1
    6V         3A        6W     18-ABB    000123
    8V         10A       25W    25-ASB    461233
    10V        23A       10W    18-ABB    248811
   File2
    2V         10A       5W     25-ASB    461643
    1V         2A        10W    18-ABB    656474
```

Comment: Look into using Perl for your task.  The overhead to learn is relatively low, and it was designed for processing text documents.

Comment: Thanks, is Perl something like HTML where you need a web based host to host the code?

Comment: What is *step 2* exactly? It is very unclear. Step 1 is easy, all you do is type `cat *.csv > MASTER` or, if you are on Windows (you don't give any clues), you can do `TYPE *.csv > MASTER`

Comment: Perl scripting is something which you can do completely on your own computer with no web hosting whatsoever.  It's the way to go for your problem.

Comment: My apologise for the lack of information. Not too sure what information I should really provide. Yes I am running on Windows.
To explain on step 2,

Basically the csv is a list of data from multiple machines. E.g there are 10 machines in the csv file and each machine parameter are voltage, current, power and error code in each column. I want step 2 to output the result from the master and tell me straight away which particular machine has an error code (e.g 18-ABB is the error code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Delete any old output files, ignoring any error messages
DEL MASTER.CSV ERROR.CSV 2>NUL:

REM Keep track of file number in FNUM
SET /A FNUM=1

REM Loop through all files whose names look like "2015-03-01.CSV"
FOR %%A IN ( *-*-*.csv ) DO (
   SET FNAME=%%A
   CALL :PROCESSFILE
   SET /A FNUM+=1
)
GOTO :EOF

REM ######################################################################
REM PROCESSFILE SUBROUTINE
REM ######################################################################
:PROCESSFILE
SET /A LNUM=1

REM New file, append its name to MASTER
ECHO %FNAME% >> MASTER.CSV
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (%FNAME%) DO (
   SET LINE=%%L
   CALL :PROCESSLINE
   SET /A LNUM+=1
)
GOTO :EOF


REM ######################################################################
REM PROCESSLINE SUBROUTINE
REM ######################################################################
:PROCESSLINE
FOR /F "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%T in ("%LINE%") DO (
   ECHO %LINE% >> MASTER.CSV
   IF %LNUM% EQU 1 (
      REM Output header line to ERROR if processing first file
      IF %FNUM% EQU 1 ECHO %LINE%  >> ERROR.CSV
      REM Output filename to ERROR for all files
      ECHO %FNAME% >> ERROR.CSV
   ) ELSE (
      REM Output lines where field 4 is not "-" to ERROR
      IF NOT "%%W" == "-" ECHO %LINE% >> ERROR.CSV
   )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to output the machines with error as csv file instead of it showing in BATCH?

Comment: Please have another look - I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks alot. We are almost there. Only 2 problems now is 1) in the error file, it is still showing all the data. I want it to isolate and only show the row or column with error code 18-ABB and 25-ASB. Also in the error file how can I input the file name that was generated in the master file? (master file captured the file name of the smaller files). 2) If let say my file name is by date e.g, 2014-04-05 and 2014-04-06 instead of file1 and file2 (which u used file*), how can I make the code to become variable based on the different file name dates like file*? Thanks alot...

Comment: Hi Mark, I have solved problem number 2 myself. Simply changing it to *-*-*.csv helps. Still require assistance for the first problem though. >_<

Comment: Try replacing the `FINDSTR` at the end with `FINDSTR "^[0-9] Voltage = -" MASTER.CSV` - that wil lfind lines that start with digits such as your filenames.

Comment: Thanks, problem 2 is solved. Changing the Findstr doesn't help much. It still shows the same data. I am also looking at other places to learn how to create the outputerror.csv that I want in my edited question aboved. Hopefully u have some answer for this. Really am seeing a good chance that this will work. :D

Comment: Try replacing the dash (minus sign) in the `FINDSTR` command with a `B` and test again to see if it finds the `18-ABB`

Comment: Tried, same result. It basically just output the same exact stuff as the master.csv

Comment: Can you click `edit` under your question and re-paste the *exact contents* of one of your input files into your question please?

Comment: I changed the code to be a bit more tolerant of your input file format - maybe copy it again and have another try please.

Comment: I will update the question and paste the exact content tomorrow. Currently out of office. Will also try the edited code later. :)

Comment: Hey mark, the updated code still doesn't work the way I wanted. I will post the exact content tomorrow for you. ;)

Comment: Please have another look, I have reworked it completely. It should be easy enough to follow, although the Windows BATCH syntax is pretty awful compared to the `awk` version.

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry that I didnt reply. I tried the code and the error.csv is still showing non-error data.

Comment: Send you the e-mail. ;)

Comment: Ok, I am taking a look. I will delete my Email address above to avoid getting any spam from others.

Comment: Ok, it should work now. It didn't work before because your CSV files are not how you showed them! You showed them with spaces between the fields but they actually have commas. You showed the headers as being underlined, but they are not. You showed a "0" for no error, when in fact your files contain "-" when there is no error :-) Hopefully it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually MUCH easier using `awk` - in fact it is only 2 lines of code! I would suggest downloading `awk.exe` from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm). It is INCREDIBLY powerful and will help with any scripting or text processing task.

The manual is available [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf).

The whole thing then becomes, many lines of comment and 2 lines of code (the third and the last line), which you run just the same as my other all-Windows solution.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Print the contents of all CSV files whose names look like a date, e.g. 2012-11-01.csv, and add their name in ahead of line 3
awk "FNR==3{print FILENAME}1" *-*-*.csv > MASTER.CSV

REM From MASTER.CSV, print the following lines out to file ERROR.CSV:
REM ... first 3 lines, i.e. Record Number < 4
REM ... any lines containing "CSV" or "csv" 
REM ... no lines with "Voltage" or "="
REM ... any lines with field4 != "0"
awk "NR<4 || /csv/ || /CSV/{print;next} /Voltage|=/{next} $4!=\""0\""" MASTER.CSV > ERROR.CSV
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the suggestion but I am currently preferring to use BATCH to do this task.